# Why does yfinance return quarter financial data, cashflows, balance sheet etc. for the last 4 years?

Tags: python, jupyter, yfinance

I'm trying to return all the available data for a particular stock using yfinance, but the issue is that yfinance is returning some of the data for the last 4 years, such as quarterly financials, balance sheet, cashflows, etc. How can I make it return the values for all the available years? Is it possible?

The code:

```
def get_info_on_stock(ticker):
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)
hist = stock.history(period = 'max')
action = stock.actions
dividend = stock.dividends
financial = stock.financials
qtr_financials = stock.quarterly_financials
balance_sheet = stock.balance_sheet
qtr_balance_sheet = stock.quarterly_balance_sheet
cashflow = stock.cashflow
qtr_cashflow = stock.quarterly_cashflow
earnings = stock.earnings
upcoming_event = stock.calendar
major_stake_holders = stock.major_holders
institutional_holders = stock.institutional_holders
hist.to_csv(f"{ticker}_hist.csv")
action.to_csv(f"{ticker}_action.csv")
dividend.to_csv(f"{ticker}_dividend.csv")          
financial.to_csv(f"{ticker}_financial.csv")
qtr_financials.to_csv(f"{ticker}_qtr_financials.csv")
balance_sheet.to_csv(f"{ticker}_balance_sheet.csv")
qtr_balance_sheet.to_csv(f"{ticker}_qtr_balance_sheet.csv")
cashflow.to_csv(f"{ticker}_cashflow.csv")
qtr_cashflow.to_csv(f"{ticker}_qtr_cashflow.csv")
earnings.to_csv(f"{ticker}_earnings.csv")
upcoming_event.to_csv(f"{ticker}_upcoming_events.csv")
major_stake_holders.to_csv(f"{ticker}_major_stake_holders.csv")
institutional_holders.to_csv(f"{ticker}_institutional_holders.csv")
```

Comment: You can first look into the yahoo finance website to see if the data is there because `yfinance` will only extract whatever is given in the website

Comment: Yes I just checked, yahoo finance is giving balance sheet, cashflows, financial etc data for the last 4 years, is there any possibility or any other library that will help me with this problem?